# Trying to Connect to Azure using Environment Credentials Not Working

Tags: c#, azure

I have been trying to run some sample code to connect to Axure for the sake of understanding and testing how my application will work on a server. In my "real" code, I have a C# Web API (.NET 4.8) which has a class library that kicks off an Azure Data Factory Pipeline. **On my local PC, this works fine because I am using Visual Studio to authenticate to Azure.**

**However, I need to test how this will work on a server.** So my sample code below is just pulling a secret from an Azure KeyVault as a POC (Proof of Concept). From my understanding, when using DefaultAzureCredential, it authenticates in the following order:

1. EnvironmentCredential
2. ManagedIdentityCredential
3. SharedTokenCacheCredential
4. VisualStudioCredential
5. VisualStudioCodeCredential
6. AzureCliCredential
7. InteractiveBrowserCredential

I would like to test using the first option, EnvironmentCredential. Looking @ the Microsoft documentation @ [EnvironmentCredential class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/identity/environmentcredential?view=azure-node-latest) I have a few options. For now, I need to use the last option, which requires I have the following Environment Variables set:

1. AZURE_TENANT_ID
2. AZURE_CLIENT_ID
3. AZURE_USERNAME
4. AZURE_PASSWORD

I am still receiving the error:

> DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included
> credentials. EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable.
> Environment variables are not fully configured.

**

- What Am I Missing? Why is This Failing?

**

More supporting evidence below.

See the screenshot below where I have set up the environment variables:
[image]

Code:

```
var client = new SecretClient(vaultUri: new Uri(url), credential: new DefaultAzureCredential());
var secretData = client.GetSecret("Secret");
```

Comment: You need to set the Environment Variables in the Azure App Service Configuration Section. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zow9.png).

Comment: Instead of setting values in System Variables set them in User Variables and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.

I have set the Environment Variables under User Variables.

[image]

Also, set these variables in the deployed Azure App => Configuration => Application Settings.

[image]

- The values which are set in the App Settings are available as Environment Variables.

[image]

- To verify whether Environment Variables are set correctly, try to retrieve the Values before calling `DefaultAzureCredential`.
- Comment the code related to retrieving the KeyVault and try to display the Environment Variables.

***Ex:***

```cs
string tenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_AZURE_TENANT_ID");
```

Code to retrieve secrets fro mKeyVault.

```cs
var kvURL = "https://KV15June.vault.azure.net/";
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvURL), credential);

var secret1 = client.GetSecret("Secret1").Value.Value;
```

As you are using **Username and password:** to authenticate, make sure the account which you are using is not MFA Enabled as mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.environmentcredential?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: Thank you Harshitha! Bringing this up to the User Variables section did the trick. Also, +1 for letting me know that this solution is viable when using MFA, which we are. However, I did receive an error message telling me since I have MFA enabled I cannot use this method, so I consider this an answer.

Comment: Yes,the account with MFA is not supported to use username and password.Even I got the same error.Instead try to use the Azure CLIENT SECRET.